# SQL: Group by date

Tags: c#, sql, razor

I'm looking for a SQL wizard to help me solve a little problem, I was told that my code was a bit uneffective and that it might be solved to work better with a better SQL query, so first of all, this is my current code.

```
var days = convertEndDate.Subtract(convertStartDate).TotalDays + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
{
    var getData = "SELECT (kg*rep*sett) as weight, (kg/max) as avg, (rep*sett) as reps, date FROM Test WHERE date = @0 AND exercise < 4";
    var getPeak = "SELECT MAX(kg/max) as peak FROM Test WHERE date = @0 AND exercise < 4";
    db.Execute(getData, dt);
    db.Execute(getPeak, dt);
    //Resets the value to 0 for next foreach loop.
    sumKG = 0;
    totReps = 0;
    avg = 0;
    //Adds a day to the date its currently was checking.
    nextDay = dt.AddDays(1);
    dt = nextDay;

    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData, dt))
    {
        var total = c.weight;
        var reps = c.reps;
        var calcAvg = c.avg * c.reps;
        avg += calcAvg;
        totReps += reps;
        sumKG += total;
    }
    foreach (var d in db.Query(getPeak, dt))
    {
        if (d.peak != null)
        {
            peak = d.peak;
        }
    }

    if (sumKG > 0)
    {
        var sumKGs = sumKG + "kg";
        completeAvg = avg / totReps;
        <a>@sumKGs,  @dt.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd MMM, yyyy"), @completeAvg.ToString("0.#%"), @totReps, @peak.ToString("0.#%")</a> <br />

    }
}
```

So currently this does work as I want it, but first I enter a startdate and a enddate, then I calculate the number of days between those days and use that as the limit in my `for` loop, i.e. (1 < amount of days between dates), and then the `foreach` loop gets all the data on that first day, then it repeats until the `for` loop reaches the limit, ofc.

However, is there are 100 days between selected days, it will run the SQL query 100 times, and there might be a better solution for this? And also, there are 2 queries so it will do a query request 200 times, this because I couldn't figure out how to combine the 2 queries, not even sure if its possible when one is using MAX(kg/max) which only selects one value where as the other query selects more values when there may be many rows in the database containing the same date.

Anyone know how to do this better?

PS. not a MVC project

Comment: Who ever told you this would be done a lot better in SQL query, he was correct, toss in some sample data and lets refactor this. Personally when it's come to things where you work with Data sets (as this one) and not row by row ... I would go for SQL ... code behind (C#) i use it more for row by row calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the queries.

```
SELECT 
            SUM(kg*rep*sett) as weight, 
            SUM(kg/max) as avg, 
            SUM(rep*sett) as reps, 
            t.date,
            pk.peak
            FROM Test t
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(kg / max) as peak, date FROM Test WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4 group by date) as pk
            on t.date = pk.date
        WHERE t.date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY t.date, pk.peak
```

Comment: `In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ Select clause = pk,peak ]`

Comment: that was the error that I got, but this looks like it would be all that I need once it works! but am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: if its relevant, im using .sdf database, pretty sure it's SQL Server Compact, in webmatrix, I've come to know that different types has there limitations or something

Comment: Add pk.peak to the GROUP BY. I have modified my answer. Not sure if this will work in compact edition. I never worked with it.

Answer (score 2):

As you said the query can be improved by grouping the results you want, since you only want the summatory. The first query must be:

```
SELECT
    sum((kg*rep*sett)) as weight,
    sum((kg/max)) as avg,
    sum((rep*sett)) as reps,
    date
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date between @0 and @1
    AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY
    date
```

You change the date from an equal to a between pasing the initial and end date you need.With this you will return from the sql all the information you need, and u only need a for loop to print it on the screen.

Comment: This is absolutely golden!! This worked very nice! Anyhow, is there a way to incorporate my second query into this as well, the one with `MAX(kg/max) AS peak` ? And also, what does one call this kind of SQL magic, so I can make the title more relevant for others looking for this?